# Backbone.history.navigate doesn't save parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have some routes:

```
routes: {
    "": "main",
    "!/": "main",
    "!/page": "page",
    "!/page/:id": "page"
},
```

Then I have some html link, for example:

```
<a href="site.com/#!/page/3">my link</a>
```

If i press to my link I access to url `site.com/#!/page/3` and it's ok for me. But if I have this link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Backbone.history.navigate('!/page/3', {trigger:true});">my link</a>
```

I access to url `site.com/#!/page/` (without `id=3`). Id is still defined. But after page reloading, I have a problem with my ID, because I have url: `site.com/#!/page`, and ID is not defined.

How can I navigate in Backbone with the following link tag?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Backbone.history.navigate('!/page/3', {trigger:true});">my link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone routing uses fragment just like any other anchor links would. You just need to use the `href` as it's suppose to be used:

```
<a href="#!/page/3">my link</a>
```

When clicking a link like this one, there's no need to set `trigger` to true as it's the default behavior. Backbone listens for `hashchange` or `popstate` events and triggers the route when necessary.

---

Also, the `routes` hash could be simplified:

```
routes: {
    "*anything": "main",
    "!/page(/:id)": "page"
},
```

See the [`routes` documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes).

> Routes can contain parameter parts, `:param`, which match a single URL
>   component between slashes; and splat parts `*splat`, which can match any
>   number of URL components. Part of a route can be made optional by
>   surrounding it in parentheses `(/:optional)`.