# Changing URL using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I view my backbone module with

> http://localhost/src/index.html#test_module

URL.
But I need to view another module like

> http://localhost/src/index.html#test_module/another_module

NOTE:

My backbone view is using `Backbone.history.navigate(another_module, {trigger:true});` but it gives me a URL like

> http://localhost/src/index.html#another_module

Comment: I explain in details [how the routing works with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442604/1218980), _spoiler alert: it's just links._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try like this.

```
Backbone.history.navigate("test_module/another_module", { trigger: true });
```

Read the [documentation on `navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) for more.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Backbone Routers](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) as a best parctice while developing using backbone. You can read through the documentation for better understanding.